# Parse Cloud code, first steps - parse deploy says 'no files to upload'

Tags: parse-platform

I'm trying to get Parse Cloud thing to work on my Mac, but after I did the command `parse new dir` and I want to call `parse deploy`, (after changing the dir), it says `no files to upload`. That's it, it's just the basic "Getting started" tutorial and I can't get it to work, no matter what I do.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out the problem was with the path to the projects - there were spaces, and '[' and ']' characters, which apparently Parse cannot parse, so it returned zero files.

When I moved the project directory to the Documents folder, everything works as expected.